# Can't install Spyder through Anaconda Navigator

Tags: windows-10, anaconda, python-3.6, spyder

I cannot install Spyder through Anaconda Navigator. I am a complete beginner when it comes to Python and I have no idea what's going wrong.

I have to create a new environment and open a project there.

What I did so far is: through Anaconda Navigator (1.9.7) I created a new environment (with Python 3.6). Then, for this specific environment I try to install Spyder. I click the 'install' button, a progress bar appears and then nothing happens.

I tried the same steps on friend's laptop and when I click install there, the progress bar also appears. When it's done the 'install' button changes to 'launch'. The only difference that I see between our computers is that I have Windows10 and he has a Macbook. I don't know whether this could be the problem somehow.

How can I install Spyder for a specific environment? What's going wrong with my installation in Anaconda Navigator?

Also, when I try to install Spyder through Anaconda Prompt (with Administrator privileges), I get the following error:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(568): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::openssl-1.1.1b-he774522_1'.
PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\eweli\\Anaconda3\\envs\\HAABSA\\Library\\bin\\libssl-1_1-x64.dll'
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue today, and weirdly a lot of versions didn't work out for me. However, what worked was to go to anaconda prompt, activate the environment and then type

```
conda install -c conda-forge spyder
```

Answer (score 1):

To install spyder, go to the command line and to the directory where you work. Activate your virtual environment by typing

`conda activate environment_name`

Then once that returns just type

`conda install spyder`

This should install spyder in your virtual environment.

Comment: Does it give you any messages or does the installation process just run endlessly.

Comment: I just added the whole error code that I get after 'conda install spyder' to the main question.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by going to the directory where the file `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` is located (in your case, `C:\Users\eweli\Anaconda3\envs\HAABSA\Library\bin\`). Then, I removed the file (by cutting and pasting it to the desktop, just to be safe) and ran the installation command again in an Anaconda prompt (with admin rights):

```
conda install -c anaconda spyder
```

After that, the installation went smoothly and a new version of `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` was created in the corresponding directory (thus I deleted the one I moved previously).

Answer (score 0):

Go the directory of your environement in terminal and type :

```
conda install -c anaconda spyder
```

it worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for this problem is the incompatibility between the Python version and Spyder version. I just installed Spyder 3.11.0 and when I tried to install on top of it, I got an error. A few days ago, I installed version 3.10.0 and didn't have any problems when I tried to install on top of it. I will try again today and edit with the results.

Edit:
It is definitely caused by the python version. I tried the same way today with the python 3.10.8 version and there was no problem. It makes more sense to set up an environment with a python version released 5-6 months ago instead of installing the latest version, or if you set up an environment directly with a prompt without choosing any python version, you will not have any problems.
https://www.python.org/doc/versions/